# How to get file from image uri to upload to server

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to get a file from image uri from two way: 1. Camera 2. Gallery in both of these ways there is no straightforward way to get the image file and it is taking up a lot of time

```
private val takeImageResult =
        registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture()) { isSuccess ->
            if (isSuccess) {
                latestTmpUri?.let { uri ->
                    tempFile = File(uri.toString())
                    binding.userImage.setImageURI(uri)
                }
            }
        }

    private val selectImageFromGalleryResult =
        registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()) { uri: Uri? ->
            uri?.let {
                latestTmpUri = uri
                tempFile = File(uri.toString())
                binding.userImage.setImageURI(it)
            }
        }
```

Comment: The  file is behind the uri. Use the uri directly to read or upload the file. You do not need a path for that. File class not usable. You are #123 this year who comes with this problem.

Comment: @blackapps Can you please elaborate and how it works, I am kinda new to this, thanks