# image upload successfully but pdf not uploaded in retrofit 2 in android java

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I can upload image successfully, using this code pdf file not uploaded. I am also using FileUtils library for upload file. Please any one help for upload pdf using this code. thanks in advance.

```
public class RetakeAnswerPaperUploadForm extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText stdAnsUploadNote;
    ImageView fileAttachment;
    TextView uploadedFileName;
    Button btnSubmitAnsPaper;
    String token, stdNote, studentID;
    private String selectedPdf;
    int retake_reg_id;

    private ListView imageList;
    private List<Uri> pdfs = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_retake_answer_paper_upload_form);
        this.setFinishOnTouchOutside(true);
        this.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);

        stdAnsUploadNote = findViewById(R.id.stdAnsUploadNote);
        fileAttachment = findViewById(R.id.fileAttachment);
        uploadedFileName = findViewById(R.id.uploadedFileName);
        btnSubmitAnsPaper = findViewById(R.id.btnSubmitAnsPaper);

        btnSubmitAnsPaper.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("student_info", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        studentID = sharedPreferences.getString("stdID","WUB");

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        token = bundle.getString("token");
        retake_reg_id = bundle.getInt("retake_reg_id");

        fileAttachment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setType("application/pdf"); //allow any image file type.
                //intent.setType("image/*"); //allow any image file type.
                intent.putExtra(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT, true);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

            }
        });

        btnSubmitAnsPaper.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                uploadAnsFileToServer();
            }
        });
    }
```

This is onActivity code...
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

```
        if(resultCode !=RESULT_CANCELED){

            switch (requestCode){
                case 1:
                    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && data !=null){

                        btnSubmitAnsPaper.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        Uri pdf = data.getData();
                        selectedPdf = FileUtils.getPath(RetakeAnswerPaperUploadForm.this,pdf);
                        uploadedFileName.setText(selectedPdf);
                    }
            }

        }
    }
```

This is file upload method....

```
    public void uploadAnsFileToServer(){
        MultipartBody.Part attachment = null;
        if (selectedPdf != null){
            btnSubmitAnsPaper.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            try {
                File file = new File(Uri.parse(selectedPdf).getPath());
                if (file.exists()){
                    RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/*"),file);
                    attachment = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("attachment",file.getName(),requestBody);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        stdNote = stdAnsUploadNote.getText().toString();
        RequestBody retake_id = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), String.valueOf(retake_reg_id));
        RequestBody student_note = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), stdNote);
        RequestBody student_id = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), studentID);

        Call<String> ansPaperSaveCall = ApiClient.getStudentService().studentAnsPaperSaveData("Bearer "+token,attachment,retake_id,student_note,student_id);
        ansPaperSaveCall.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
                System.out.println(response.body());
                Intent intent = new Intent(RetakeAnswerPaperUploadForm.this, StudentRegistration.class);
                intent.putExtra("token",token);
                startActivity(intent);
                Toast.makeText(RetakeAnswerPaperUploadForm.this,"Answer Paper successfully submit.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
                System.out.println(t.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(RetakeAnswerPaperUploadForm.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is my post method code....

```
@Multipart
    @POST("single_file_upload.php?path=students/save_answer_paper_with_attachment")
    Call<String> studentAnsPaperSaveData(
            @Header ("Authorization") String token,
            @Part MultipartBody.Part attachment,
            @Part("retake_id")RequestBody retake_id,
            @Part("student_note")RequestBody student_note,
            @Part("reg_id")RequestBody student_id
    );
```

Comment: `selectedPdf = FileUtils.getPath(RetakeAnswerPaperUploadForm.this,pdf);
                  ` That is nonsense. And .. we cannot see what you do. Use uri = data.getData() to upload the file. You cannot use the File class for an uri.

Comment: #124: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72010019/how-to-get-file-from-image-uri-to-upload-to-server

Comment: Thanks blackapps, I am new an android, I cant understand your answer. Please can you explain with my using code. thanks.